# How to set "modify" ACL on a Windows file using Java

Tags: java, windows, file, permissions, acl

How do you set the Windows ACL using Java 7's File API so that it mimics adding the user/group and the following options:

For example, in the OS Properties dialog, you can select the following for basic write access:

- ☑ **Modify**
- ☑ Read and Execute (auto-selected)
- ☑ List folder Contents (auto-selected)
- ☑ Read (auto-selected)
- ☑ Write (auto-selected)

However, when I use similar options using Java 7's File API, it instead selects:

- ☑ Special

  - ☑ Advanced (NOT Edit, Click User or Group, View)

    - Show Advanced Permissions
    - Advanced Permissions

      - ☑ (Bunch of checkboxes)

Not only is this harder to administer (traversing dialogs is easier to miss something), it doesn't behave the same was as simply clicking those boxes.  Some of the UAC prompts behave differently.  Worse, it's harder to toggle the permissions (e.g. from the Windows desktop) due to the dialog traversing, leaving more chance of making a mistake.

How do I use Java to set these checkboxes?

```
UserPrincipal authenticatedUsers = path.getFileSystem().getUserPrincipalLookupService()
        .lookupPrincipalByName("Authenticated Users");
AclFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, AclFileAttributeView.class);

// Create ACL to give "Authenticated Users" "modify" access
AclEntry entry = AclEntry.newBuilder()
        .setType(AclEntryType.ALLOW)
        .setPrincipal(authenticatedUsers)
        .setPermissions(DELETE, DELETE_CHILD, LIST_DIRECTORY, READ_DATA, READ_ATTRIBUTES, ADD_FILE, WRITE_DATA, WRITE_ATTRIBUTES)
        .build();

List<AclEntry> acl = view.getAcl();
acl.add(0, entry); // insert before any DENY entries
view.setAcl(acl);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to mimic the Windows Properties file permissions by making a folder that I wanted to mimic, setting the values through the Properties dialog, then echoing them back out...

```
// Echo ACL
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\myfolder");

UserPrincipal authenticatedUsers = path.getFileSystem().getUserPrincipalLookupService()
        .lookupPrincipalByName("Authenticated Users");

AclFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, AclFileAttributeView.class);
for(AclEntry entry : view.getAcl()) {
    if(entry.principal().equals(authenticatedUsers)) {
        System.out.println("=== flags ===");
        for (AclEntryFlag flags : entry.flags()) {
            System.out.println(flags.name());
        }

        System.out.println("=== permissions ===");
        for (AclEntryPermission permission : entry.permissions()) {
            System.out.println(permission.name());
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
=== flags ===
DIRECTORY_INHERIT
FILE_INHERIT

=== permissions ===
WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS
WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
DELETE
WRITE_DATA
READ_ACL
APPEND_DATA
READ_ATTRIBUTES
READ_DATA
EXECUTE
SYNCHRONIZE
READ_NAMED_ATTRS
```

Then, I was able to plug these values back into my original example:

```
UserPrincipal authenticatedUsers = path.getFileSystem().getUserPrincipalLookupService()
        .lookupPrincipalByName("Authenticated Users");
AclFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, AclFileAttributeView.class);

// Create ACL to give "Authenticated Users" "modify" access
AclEntry entry = AclEntry.newBuilder()
        .setType(AclEntryType.ALLOW)
        .setPrincipal(authenticatedUsers)
        .setFlags(DIRECTORY_INHERIT,
                  FILE_INHERIT)
        .setPermissions(WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS,
                        WRITE_ATTRIBUTES,
                        DELETE,
                        WRITE_DATA,
                        READ_ACL,
                        APPEND_DATA,
                        READ_ATTRIBUTES,
                        READ_DATA,
                        EXECUTE,
                        SYNCHRONIZE,
                        READ_NAMED_ATTRS)
        .build();
```

... and now "Modify" is checked exactly as desired.

Comment: Just FYI if your code needs to run in different languages lookupPrincipalByName("Authenticated Users") won't work, because say for instance on a French machine that group is called: "utilisateurs authentifiés". There is a language independent SID for this group "S-1-5-11" which you can find here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers
However, there's no way to use the Java API with that SID to get the UserPrincipal. I had to write native C++ code to make this work for me.

Comment: @ThomasIbbotson if you eventually develop a way to do this with JNA, please share.  The JNA team is very receptive to API additions, especially those that fix major issues like this.