# Restrict file access on Windows for ADMIN only (Java)

Tags: java, file, permissions, windows-10, acl

I would like to remove all the permissions (read, write, etc.) on a file with a given path for other groups and users except for administrators of the OS (Windows 10). This could be done with a script that would receive paths of those files.
I had seen various ways to accomplish setting the write or read permissions to owner or all the users using Java File class.

So for example:

```
File f = new File("f:\\program.txt"); 

// Check if the Writable permission 
// can be set to new value 
if (f.setWritable(true)) { 
       // Display that the Writable permission 
       // is be set to new value 
       System.out.println("Writable permission is set"); 
}
```

But this is not the desired behavior for me actually.. I want only the admin to have access to the specified file. What API would I use to go on to implement this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You modify file access based on Windows "group".  This can actually be done with native Java, using [java.nio.file.attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html).  Look here for an example: [How to set “modify” ACL on a Windows file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700035/).  BTW, you also need to decide exactly what kind of "Admin": for example, "local" admin and/or one of (many!)" "domain" admins?

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes, thank you for the link, it was quite helpful!